# Is it a good practice to use an MVC application's own Web API for Ajax bindings?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

I'm writting an application that has many Ajax widgets (Kendo-UI to be percise). It's starting to get messy to have all those Ajax responses without the standard controllers so I was starting to consider making each entities their own controller. If I'm taking the time to do this, I figured I might as well go foward and do those as WebAPIs since I was planning to do this in a not so close future, but hey, it would be done already...

So my question is: Is it a good practice to use an MVC application's own Web API as a Ajax Widget feeds or is there any reason to stick with standard Controllers?

I've seen some arguments about performance, but I don't think this applies to this situation. I believe it was more of a "Controller calling WebAPI" situation which has obvious performance hits. But since it's already a client side Ajax call, weither it goes into a standard MVC Controller or a WebAPI controller shouldn't change a thing, would it?

Edit

Additional information regarding the project:

- I am using Entity Framework for the data access.
- I have a repository pattern going on with UnitOfWork.
- I am using proper a MVC structure (EF POCOs AutoMapped to DTO POCOs in the repository and fed into View Models by the controllers)
- This is a MVC 4 project on .NET 4.0
- There is a lot of database relationships (specially for the object I'm working with at the moment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about "good practice", but it's certainly not "bad practice".  I see no difference whether you do it in the app or a different one.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a good thing but only if what you are doing in the API is kept as generic as possible to other applications and services can reuse the API.

Both the applications I have written and continue to maintain use pretty much the exact same stack as your app.

I have recently re-factored one of the applications to use the API for all the common things like lists that I'm binding to Kendo ComboBoxes etc. in my views. Its a fairly large application that re-uses a lot of the same lists such as states, priorities, complexities across various Entities and views so it makes sense to put those in the API.

I haven't gone as far as going the whole hog through.  I draw the line with things like this:

```
public ActionResult GetAjaxProjectsList([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json((DataSourceResult)GetProjectsList().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

That is very specific to how the Kendo Grid wants the data back.  Nothing else I have connecting to this app will use this data in this format so I keep it in the controller.

In short...  I use the API for common things within the same MVC app and things that I allow to be used by other applications or services, like Excel.